# bind data to vue model dynamically in component

Tags: javascript, html, templates, vue.js, reactive-programming

I'm trying to make a simple form that will accept user's input for different types of currency.

Here's a (broken) fiddle that hopefully gets across what I want to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/4erk8yLj/7/

I'd like my component to bind data to my root vue instance, but I'm not sure if my v-model string is allowable. Check it out:

```
Vue.component('conversion-row', {
  props: ['currency', 'values'],
  template: '<div>{{currency}}:</div><div><input v-model="values[currency]></div><',
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currencies: ['USD', 'BTC'],
    values: {
      'BTC': '',
      'USD': ''
    }
  }


});
```

template:

```
<div id="app">
  <li>
    <conversion-row is li v-for="currency in currencies" v-bind:currency="currency">
    </conversion-row>
  </li>
</div>
```

What's a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things you might need to correct:

First, the `data` property must be a function rather than an object. This allows every instance to get data recomputed every time it is being created, see:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      currencies: ['USD', 'BTC'],
      values: {
        'BTC': 'BTC Value',
        'USD': 'USD Value',
      },
    };
  }
});
```

Second, `<conversion-row>` doesn't have `values` property bound. Here's what you can do:

```
<div id="app">
  <li v-for="currency in currencies">
    <conversion-row :currency="currency" :values="values"></conversion-row>
  </li>
</div>
```

Last, the component should always aim for one root element (wrapper) and then you can nest as many children inside as you want. What's more, instead of using `v-model`, you can bind `value` which is the proper way to pass a value to an input (one-way data binding), check the following:

```
Vue.component('conversion-row', {
  props: ['currency', 'values'],
  template: '<div>{{currency}}:<input type="text" :value="values[currency]"></div>'
});
```

There's more improvements you could possibly make here like re-thinking if you need to pass `values` as well as `currency` to the `conversion-row` but I'm pretty sure you'll figure it out later on.

All that above will make your code run and execute properly, here's the working example (fork of yours):

- https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsmolinski/mp8m0ben/1/

Does this help?

Not sure what you're aiming for in terms of using `v-model`, but here's an example of working `v-model` (based on your example):

```
Vue.component('conversion-row', {
  props: ['currency', 'values'],
  template: '<div>{{currency}}:<input type="text" v-model="values[currency]"></div>'
});
```

And the corresponding template:

```
<div id="app">  
  <p><strong>USD Value:</strong> {{ values.USD }}</p>
  <p><strong>BTC Value:</strong> {{ values.BTC }}</p>

  <br>

  <li v-for="currency in currencies">
    <conversion-row :currency="currency" :values="values"></conversion-row>
  </li>
</div>
```

You can find it under the following URL:

- https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsmolinski/0xng8v86/2/

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.